# SQL generate sequential id's based on other column(s)

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Probably best I explain what I'm after with an example :)

Say I have the following table

```
SELECT *
INTO #OrderRanking
FROM (
    SELECT 'Jim', 1000
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jim', 500
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jim', 500
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jim', 3000
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Bob', 1000
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Bob', 2000
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Bob', 500
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Bob', 500
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Fred', 500
) AS t(Customer, OrderTotal)
```

What I want is the following result in a `SELECT` statement

```
Customer, OrderTotal, CustomerId
'Jim', 1000, 1
'Jim', 500, 1
'Jim', 500, 1
'Jim', 3000, 1
'Bob', 1000, 2
'Bob', 2000, 2
'Bob', 500, 2
'Bob', 500, 2
'Fred', 500, 3
```

My actual query is a bit more complex, where the source columns is more than 2.

Comment: Does `Jim` have to be `1` or do you just want the customers with the same name to have the same id?

Comment: No he doesn't have to be one. Just a unique id will suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a pillock,

```
SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Customer DESC)
FROM #OrderRanking
```

I think this should cover all cases!

Answer (score 1):

```
select customer, ordertotal, dense_rank() over(order by total desc, customer asc)
from (select *, sum(ordertotal) over(partition by customer) total from  #orderranking) t
```

Comment: Interesting approach! However, if two customers have the same total, then it will generate the same id

Comment: Sorry I thought you wanted the customer with more total orders be first in the ranking. If you just need different numbers for different customers then the sql you posted will do; otherwise if you'd wanted both conditions (ranking by total and different customer numbers) i've edited the query to satisfy it.